# Rails ActionController::Live connection dropped

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After my `ActionController::Live` listens for about 5 minutes, I get the following in my browser and my `EventSource` drops the connection.

`EventSource's response has a MIME type ("text/html") that is not "text/event-stream". Aborting the connection.`

Any idea where that 'text/html' request is coming from?

I'm using Unicorn and Nginx.

This is my backend code:

```
def listen_to_checkins
  response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/event-stream'

  redis = Redis.new
  redis.psubscribe("checkin.*.#{current_branch.id}") do |on|
    puts "subscribed..."
    on.pmessage do |pattern, event, data|
      puts "got message..."
      response.stream.write("event: checkin.create\n")
      response.stream.write("data: #{data}\n\n")
    end
  end

 # rails 4.2 uses ClientDisconnected instead of IOError
 rescue ClientDisconnected
   logger.info "Stream closed"
 rescue IOError
   logger.info "Stream error"
 ensure
   redis.quit
   response.stream.close
 end
end
```

And this is my coffee:

```
ready = ->
  if !source
    source = new EventSource('/validator/listen_to_checkins')
    source.addEventListener 'message', (e) ->
      console.log "got message"

    source.addEventListener 'checkin.create', (e) ->
      console.log "got back: #{e.data}"
      get_last_checkins()

    source.addEventListener 'open', (e) ->
      console.log "opened"

    source.addEventListener 'error', (e) ->
      console.log "error"
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. I ended up reconnecting on error on the client's side. I hope this helps someone until I find a more elegant solution.

```
ready = ->
  if !source
    reconnect()

reconnect = ->
  if ($("meta[name=listen_to_checkins]").attr("content") == "true")
    console.log("reconnecting")
    source = new EventSource('/validator/listen_to_checkins')
    source.addEventListener 'message', (e) ->
      console.log "got message"

    source.addEventListener 'checkin.create', (e) ->
      console.log "got back: #{e.data}"
      show_checkins(JSON.parse(e.data))

    source.addEventListener 'error', (e) ->
      # reload page on error if we're listening to checkins
      setTimeout ()->
        reconnect()
      , 1000

      console.log "error"
      console.log e
```